# Xcode 12 Beta 3: App Store Connect Operation Error

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, app-store-connect

ERROR ITMS-90475: "Invalid Bundle. Your app supports Multitasking on iPad, so you must include the UILaunchStoryboardName key in your bundle, 'com.Thunder-Flare.Expenses’. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW40)."

This application was made with SwiftUI interface and SwiftUI lifecycle

Comment: So just add launch storyboard, or copy from UIKit life-cycle new project created from template... and add that key into Info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on new file and Launch Screen. Then get rid of the existing launch screen details on the plist file and add Launch screen interface file name, in string area add the file name.

Then design your storyboard however you like!